# Invoke-DbaQuery not working on new server, Cannot find an overload for "SqlCommand"

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

I've ran the install script both without and with the -Force parameter from the [Getting Started](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/#getting-started) doc on github

```
Install-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

This code works on my old server but it's not working on the new one.

```
$Params =
@{
    Column1 = $Column1;
    Column2 = $Column2
}


$InsertQuery =
"           
    insert into dbo.Table
    (
        Column1,
        Column2
    )
    values
    (
        @Column1,
        @Column2
    )
"


Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance "server" -Database "database" -Query $TableSizeInsertQuery -SqlParameter $Params
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error connecting to [server]: Cannot find an overload for "SqlCommand" and the argument count: "2". At C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.1.46\allcommands.ps1:92862 char:9
+         throw $records[0]
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (server:String) [], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : dbatools_Invoke-DbaQuery
```

I've also ran these commands:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
import-module -name SqlServer
install-module -name dbatools
Import-Module -name dbatools
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sqlserver` and `dbatools` modules have conflicts when loaded into the same session if you import `sqlserver` first. See https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/issues/7897

The solution is to either not import `sqlserver` when using `dbatools`, or import `dbatools` first.

Comment: yup, adding import-module dbatools as the first line of the function fixed my issue

Comment: How can we resolve the situation if somehow sqlserver module was imported first without closing the current powershell session and opening new one?